# "unadd" a file to svn before commit

Tags: svn

I was in the middle of doing a recursive svn add/commit, and a folder which did not have the proper ignore properties was included. I've got about 100 uploaded binary files versioned now, but I haven't committed yet.

What is the easiest way to 'undo' this, without deleting all the documents?

Answer (score 252, accepted):

Use `svn revert --recursive folder_name`

---

## Warning

> `svn revert` is inherently dangerous, since its entire purpose is to throw away data — namely, your uncommitted changes. Once you've reverted, Subversion provides *no way* to get back those uncommitted changes.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html

Comment: To expand upon this - `revert` without a revision specified undoes any changes which occurred since the last checkout, including add/delete scheduling changes, for the specified file(s).

Comment: where folder_name is the parent folder of the folder where you did the "Add" command

Comment: This answer is dangerously incorrect - it will unstage your changes BY REMOVING YOUR LOCAL COPIES OF THE FILES.

Brian Lacy's answer below is much better.

Comment: Guys, this answers the original question: a file or folder that was added, then reverted, only goes back to being non versioned, without being deleted. That's exactly what the question asks. If you use it on modified files, of course it reverts them: but that wasn't the question. That's even the very specific use case shown on the linked page!

Comment: @JulienLebosquain Ok, I guess you and I understand this phrase differently: *without deleting all the documents*. Unfortunately, `svn revert` does also delete the newly added *changes* in the working copy, by restoring the lastest `HEAD` version. I removed my downvote, but I still feel the warning is important.

Comment: @jpaugh if the files aren't committed there wont be any copy in the working dir to overwrite any local changes

Answer (score 169):

`svn rm --keep-local folder_name`

Note: In svn 1.5.4 svn rm deletes unversioned files even when --keep-local is specified. See http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2009-11/0058.shtml for more information.

Comment: This is good to know as it allows you to simply undo the "svn add" without losing changes!

Comment: Are you certain SVN 1.5.4 deletes unversioned files? The report wasn't reproductible, and there's no other email about that.

Comment: This is the better answer if you want to "unadd" the files, but still keep them. After this command, the files will still be there with the ? status.

Answer (score 33):

Try `svn revert filename` for every file you don't need and haven't yet committed. Or alternatively do `svn revert -R folder` for the problematic folder and then re-do the operation with correct ignoring configuration.

[From the documentation:](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html)

```
 you can undo any scheduling operations:

$ svn add mistake.txt whoops
A         mistake.txt
A         whoops
A         whoops/oopsie.c

$ svn revert mistake.txt whoops
Reverted mistake.txt
Reverted whoops
```

Comment: No! Revert is unsafe, as it looses all local changes

Comment: @jpaugh - This is exactly what I wrote in the answer, no?

Comment: What the OP asked for (and what I was expecting) was a command to undo the add *without* loosing local changes. `svn revert`. None of the answers here mention the fact that local changes will be lost by the revert.

Answer (score 5):

Full process (Unix svn package):

Check files are not in SVN:

```
> svn st -u folder 
? folder
```

Add all (including ignored files):

```
> svn add folder
A   folder
A   folder/file1.txt
A   folder/folder2
A   folder/folder2/file2.txt
A   folder/folderToIgnore
A   folder/folderToIgnore/fileToIgnore1.txt
A   fileToIgnore2.txt
```

Remove "Add" Flag to All * Ignore * files:

```
> cd folder

> svn revert --recursive folderToIgnore
Reverted 'folderToIgnore'
Reverted 'folderToIgnore/fileToIgnore1.txt'


> svn revert fileToIgnore2.txt
Reverted 'fileToIgnore2.txt'
```

Edit svn ignore on folder

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

Add two singles lines with just the following:

```
folderToIgnore
fileToIgnore2.txt
```

Check which files will be upload and commit:

```
> cd ..

> svn st -u
A   folder
A   folder/file1.txt
A   folder/folder2
A   folder/folder2/file2.txt


> svn ci -m "Commit message here"
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. It seems it reverted only the 'add' operation, not touching the file content itself. I was scared about losing the local changes as commented on previous answers, but it seems no files were harmed.

Answer (score 3):

For Files - `svn revert filename`

For Folders - `svn revert -R folder`

Comment: No! Revert is unsafe, as it looses all local changes